# VPN Crashes Home Wireless Network

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, wireless-router, home-networking, network-adapter

I have recently started a new job working from home. We utilize FortiClient VPN and our company has an EMS server that it reaches. At home I am using a Netgear Nighthawk RS400 AC2300 and I am connected to a fiber optic modem provided by the ISP. I have now confirmed and tested that whenever I connect my work laptop, which is connected to a domain, to my home wireless network and when I do I either get a "Can't connect to this network" message even though my personal laptop, TV, and other devices are connected

OR

The entire home network crashes and goes down. I have reached out to the ISP and they are not seeing any issues from the internet into the modem. I can watch the lights on the router and when the network goes down the router does not signal that it loses connection. BUT, the entire network goes down and all devices in the house are unable to connect to the internet and the wireless network completely goes down. I have not tested whether or not the computer that is directly connected to the router loses connection, but I can confirm that once my work laptop connects to the wireless home network, the whole network goes down.

Comment: Ask the Company about this.  I have used that client on wireless and it works just fine.

Comment: "Can't connect to this network" - which network is it? Does it happen with or without the VPN? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Check the logs on your router while your system is in the broken state (use the system directly connected to the router if you need to).

Comment: @harrymc sorry for the long delay in responding. I found out that using the 2.4 GHz wifi in my home network works just fine all day while using the VPN without crashing the entire network. I have a resolution to the problem, but I am still left with questions as to what caused this issue while using the 5 GHz channel because it is all tied to the same SSID (with exception to the 2.4 and 5 at the end to differentiate the two) running on the same router. Strange.

Comment: 2.4 GHz has a longer reach than 5 GHz and can better work through walls.